# Build a TeamCity config without rebuilding dependent config

Tags: teamcity

In TeamCity*  I have Build Config A and Build Config B**.
Config B depends on Config A, so when I ask B to build it checks if A needs building first.
That's usually what I want - but I often want to tell it "just execute Config B's steps without checking if A needs rebuilding".
I can't seem to work out how to do that!

The dependency is both a Snapshot Dependency and Artifact Dependency - so it must be tied to a particular instance of Config A's build - I'm ok to have to specify this.

--

[*] TeamCity v8, but as I started setting this up v9 came out, so will move to that shortly - in case that makes a difference

[**] The names have been changed - and workflow simplified - to protect the innocent

Comment: Use Run Custom Build dialog and select appropriate dependency on 'dependencies' tab. See related [documentation page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Triggering+a+Custom+Build#TriggeringaCustomBuild-Dependencies)
Also check out 'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' option of snapshot dependency.

Comment: Yeah, I had found the Run Custom Build dialog and thought it looked promising. Unfortunately in the Dependencies tab the only options are "auto" and "rebuild" (currently set to auto). Oh, and I have 'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' set.

Answer (score 0):

'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' will only work if there are no pending changes and it's been recently built.

Are you avert to changing the dependency to not be a snapshot dependency and linking it to a particular artifact?  You can do that under artifact dependencies by selecting from the drop down "Build with specified build number" or "Latest successful build".  Of course you'd have to change it back when you were done if you wanted to switch back to snapshot dependency only.